# Background image for Chakra Provider

Tags: typescript, chakra-ui

I would like to use an image as the background for my Chakra Provider's body.

I created a code snippet as below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
const styles = {
  global: (props: GlobalStyleProps) => ({
    body: {
      fontFamily: 'body',
      color: mode('gray.800', 'whiteAlpha.900')(props),
      // bg: mode('gray.800', 'whiteAlpha.900')(props),
      backgroundImage: mode('@public/unknown.png', '@public/unknown.png')(props),
      lineHeight: 'base',
    },
    
  }),
}

const theme = extendTheme({ styles });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
  styles: {
    global: (props: GlobalStyleProps) => ({
      body: {
        backgroundImage: mode('url("@public/unknown.png")', 'url("@public/unknown.png")')(props),
      }
    })
  },
```